# Let A subset W of $P^3$ defined by $W=\{p(x) \in P^3/\int ^3_1 p(x)=0\}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let A subset $W$ of $P^3$ defined by $W=\{p(x) \in P^3/\int ^3_1 p(x)=0\}$ Is W is subspace? Find its basis and Dimension ?

My attempt : clearly $W$ is subspace because   $ap(x)+bq(x) \in W$

for basis let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$

then $\int ^3_1p(x)=0 \Rightarrow  2a_0+4a_1+\frac{28}{3}a_2+20a_3=0$ from here i am stuck

Comment: The equation at the end allows you to express $a_3$ in terms of the other $a_i $. The expression for $p (x) $ then gives you $p (x) $ as a linear combination of some polynomials, with $a_0,a_1,a_2$ as scalars. Check that these polynomials are linearly independent,  and you have your basis.

Comment: By the way, simply saying "because $ap (x)+bq (x)\in W $" is not really a proof.